# Update a pandas dataframe in each iteration and append to previous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to take a section of an existing pandas dataframe and duplicating that section with some updates in a loop. Basically, for all 273 rows of the section, I want to update the persons "GivenName"  by replacing "Name1" with "Name2", "Name3"..."Name5".

```
data1 = data[0:273] #creating the subset
data2 = data1.copy()
df = []
for i in range(4):
    data2["GivenName"] = "Name"+str(i+2) #for all 273 rows replace name
    df.append(data2)
appended_data = pd.concat(df)
```

What I end up instead is with a dataframe where only the last value "Name5" is appended 4 times instead of "Name2", "Name3"..."Name5" etc. How can I update the "GivenName" values for each iteration and append all results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or a oneliner

```
pd.concat(data[0:273].assign(GivenName=f'Name{i+2}') for i in range(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is your list `df` is just getting four references to the same `data2` DataFrame. In other words, the list looks like this:

```
[
    data2,
    data2,
    data2,
    data2
]
```

and you're setting `data2["GivenName"] = "Name5"` in the final iteration. The most straightforward way to get the behavior you're expecting is moving the DataFrame copy into the for loop:

```
df = []
for i in range(4):
    data2 = data1.copy()
    data2["GivenName"] = "Name"+str(i+2) #for all 273 rows replace name
    df.append(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

(1) `df = []` creates a list, not a dataframe. Try `df = pd.DataFrame()`

(2) `df.append(data2)` should be `df = df.append(data2)` because append does not happen in-place.

```
data1 = data[0:273] #creating the subset
data2 = data1.copy()
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(4):
    data2["GivenName"] = "Name"+str(i+2) #for all 273 rows replace name
    df = df.append(data2)
appended_data = pd.concat(df)
```